# What's a superstrat?

Tags: electric-guitar, stratocaster

There's a stratocaster with SSS pickups or HSS pickups on Fender web. But some other manufactures made some guitar that they called a *Superstrat*. What really it is? Is it have a relation with a strat? Or is it a strat that super?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A superstrat is any guitar that is basically like a strat but has upgrades and extra features. Typical upgrades that make a guitar a superstrat include:

- Upgraded tremolo (technically vibrato) unit - Floyd Rose is common
- Upgraded electronics/pickups - HSH with coil tap is popular
- Upgraded tonewoods - the body might be more of a Les Paul body made from mahogany with or without a maple cap and pickups mounted LP style
- Upgraded neck  - usually with more frets (24 is common) and/or a more sophisticated truss rod, compound radius, and higher-end tone woods

When I hear "superstrat", my mind pictures something almost exactly like [this](http://www.ibanez.co.jp/products/u_eg_page15.php?year=2015&cat_id=1&series_id=4&data_id=200&color=CL01).

Comment: a *true* superstrat has flashy colors or motifs :P

Answer (score 2):

In the 80s, guitarists started experimenting with electronics, pickups (e.g. [active pickups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pickup_%28music_technology%29#Active_and_passive_pickups)) and bridges (think the [Floyd Rose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd_Rose)) or scalloped fretboards to allow for easier access to extended techniques.

The Stratocaster being often the starting base, the result was called a "Super Strat".

In a way, the evolution of Superstrats is symbiotic with the rise of "shredders", starting with [Eddie Van Halen](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z_lwocmL9dQ), whose signature instrument is called the ["Frankenstrat"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankenstrat) and could very well be considered the prototypical Superstrat.

**TL;DR:** A Superstrat is your [garden](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/be/Yamaha_RGX521D.jpg) [variety](http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/ibanez/images/9/9e/JEM-JR_BK.gif/revision/latest?cb=20090403172355) [shredder](http://cdn.growassets.net/user_files/esp/product_images/000/010/642/xlarge.png?1389983129) [guitar](http://www.musicplayers.com/reviews/guitars/2011/images/jpxi_front.jpg), meant for ultimate playability and popular with prog metal fans.

Comment: I agree when I hear the word Superstrat I immediately think of Eddy